# Why my safeTransfer function doesn't work?

Tags: erc-20, uniswap

I am learning solidity and want to transfer tokens to others in my contract. But something blocked the way. Hope someone to help me. Below is my code:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.8.0;

contract Test {

    bytes4 private constant SELECTOR = bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transfer(address,uint256)')));

    constructor() {
    }

    function safeTransfer(address token, address to, uint value) public {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(SELECTOR, to, value));
        require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'TRANSFER_FAILED');
    }
}
```

And these are the arguments I pass to `safeTransfer` in remix on the goerli testnet.

[image]

`token`: 0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6, which is `WETH`.

And here is the error message.

[image]

I do not understand why this fails. I've tried multiple tokens and all of them just failed with the error message `TRANSFER_FAILED`

I am confident there are enough WETH token on the account I call this function.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the function `safeTransfer` on contract `Test`, the `Test` contract forwards your message and the `msg.sender` address changes to the `Test` contract's address. Therefore, the `Token` expects `Test` contract to have some tokens available.

You can choose one of the two methods explained below to proceed:

- Send some tokens to the `Test` contract address.
- Give the `Test` contract some allowance and change it to call `safeTransferFrom` to forward your tokens for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know what is wrong. But what if I want to implement a contract that when other people call this function, a certain amount of tokens can be transferred to this contract. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You need to write a function that does `token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount)`. This transfers `amount` from `msg.sender` to the contract. However, it would only succeed if the `msg.sender` already gave enough allowance to your contract's address.